# url com parâmetros retorna valor errado

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho a seguinte consulta à `api` do `Google Maps`

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muriae&destinations=Rio de Janeiro&mode=CAR&language=pt-br&sensor=false
```

Que me retorna o seguinte `array`

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Muriaé, MG, Brasil</origin_address>
<destination_address>Rio de Janeiro, RJ, Brasil</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>15350</value>
<text>4 horas 16 minutos</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>298184</value>
<text>298 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Então estou fazendo a seguinte `função` para `pegar` o `value` da `distancia`.

```
private function calculaDistancia () {

  //$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=".$this->cepOrigem."&destinations=".$this->cepDestino."&mode=".$this->mode."&language=".$this->language."&sensor=false";
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muria%C3%A9&destinations=Rio%20de%20Janeiro&mode=CAR&language=pt-br&sensor=false";

    print $url;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     

    $freteXML = simplexml_load_string($data);
    $distancia = $freteXML->row->element->distance->value;  // CalculaFrete.php on line 60

    return $distancia;

}
```

Mas está dando erro quando uso `variáveis` na função.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\hotplateprensas.com.br\_controlls\_util\CalculaFrete.php on line 60 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\hotplateprensas.com.br\_controlls\_util\CalculaFrete.php on line 60 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\hotplateprensas.com.br\_controlls\_util\CalculaFrete.php on line 60 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\php\hotplateprensas.com.br\_controlls\_util\CalculaFrete.php on line 60
```

direto no navegador retorno mas com curl() não vai.

Outra coisa,  dando `print`, a `url` imprime

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muria%C3%A9&destinations=Rio%20de%20Janeiro&mode=CAR&language=pt-br&sensor=false
```

Se eu, ao invés de usar as varáveis `php` usar a `url` diretamente na função, também dá certo.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

na url não deve conter espaços:

Solução:

```
   $this->cepDestino =  str_replace(" ","%20",$this->phpUtil->limpaCaracters($this->cepDestino));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão seria pegar o array de dados e utilizar das funções em ex:

```
$dados = array(
    'origins'=>'SP' 
    ,'language'=>'pt-br'
    ,'operators'=>array('1','2')
); 
// também é possivel com array dentro do array

$urlcoded = 'http://www.site.com/?'.http_build_query( $dados );
```

ou se preferir fazer na mão

```
$urlcoded = 'http://www.site.com/?';

foreach(dados as $k=>$v){
    $urlcoded .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
    // constroi formato key=valuecoded&key2=valuecoded2
}
$urlcoded = rtrim('$',$uelcoded);
// tira o ultimo & nao necessario
```